# Old version scipy for win64 needed

Tags: python, scipy

I'm using abaqus 6.13 which only support 64bit system. But the numpy within abaqus is 1.4.1 version, which do not support the newest 0.13.1 scipy.

I need some old version 64bit scipy (0.7.0-0.9.0) for python 2.6 (the version within abaqus) in windows, but I can't find them anywhere.

In http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ ,there's only scipy 0.13.1. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The [sourceforge downloads page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/) has sources and binaries for older versions from 0.6 upwards. The windows binaries seem to be 32-bit, so if that doesn't work for you, you may need to get the sources from the maintenance/xx branches in the [github repo](https://github.com/scipy/scipy) and build them yourself.